# Has anyone used functional testing tools to grade student lab exercises?

Tags: testing

I'm working on classes that cover software tools and languages.  Obviously the classes are going to be more valuable if the students actually **do** some of what they're supposed to be learning, so I'm planning to incorporate lab work.

Has anyone used automated functional testing tools to grade lab assignments?  Lab 1 is to install Apache, so the testing server looks to see that your lab machine is listening on port 80, and responds with the default index page.  Lab 2 is to create a page that takes `?name=MyName` and responds "Hello, MyName!", so the testing server GETs `?name=random` and expects "Hello, random!".

If you haven't used them this way yourself, what tools **might** be a good candidate?

Comment: Yes, my scheme hw 8+ years ago was graded by a scheme program. If you can get this right and fully automated, then it is a good idea. You do want to check things yourself from time to time to detect any cheating.

Answer (score 1):

> What tools might be a good candidate?

curl is always a good place to start.

pyCurl might be easier to script and automate.

Selenium can do almost anything browser-related, but it's probably overkill for such simple assignments.

Yes, I actually wrote this kind of homework-runner a long, long time ago.  So long ago, it's hard to imagine.  It run on an OS called TOPS-10.